# Accessing each character in a string in an index in a list

Tags: python, list

I am taking an input fro the user in a list format using:

```
b=list(map(str,input().strip().split()))
```

If I give the input as 'abc', all of it is stored at index 0.
I want each character of the string to be stored in a different index, how do I do that?
Output for the statement `print(b[0])` is:

```
abc
```

What I want is:

```
a
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `split` by default, splits by space.

Comment: So I remove that?

Comment: `b` is a list. You want to access to the first element of the list which is the entire inpt `abc` and then to the first letter of this input:Just do `print(b[0][0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to convert it to a list directly:

```
b=list(input()) # input "abc"
print(b) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(b[0]) # a
```

Comment: Thanks but my input needs to be a continuous string without commas or spaces.

Comment: @SafiyaHamid ...this is actually what it does,you could try it.

Comment: @SafiyaHamid Glad to help,if answer worked, consider to accept it by checking the mark besides the answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

you can do if you have one string :

`b = [str(i) for i in input()]`

Or if you have a lot of string separated with space :

`b = [str(i) for i in input().split()]`

like if your input is "abc" or "abc def"

`#input "abc" b = ["a","b","c"]`

`#input "abc def" b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`

So what it does is taking every character in the string different that " " and appending it to the list and then you can access every element that you want.

Comment: This may a be a little too much, simply use split

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @pppery yeah, I will edit my comment now, and explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you give multiple strings in one input

```
In [185]: b=list(map(lambda x: list(x)[0],input().strip().split()))
hi bye

In [186]: b
Out[186]: ['h', 'b']
```